# Initializing a std::barrier with a class member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, barrier

How do you initialize a `std::barrier` with a class member function?

```
class CMyClass {
private:
    void func() {
    }

public:
    void start() {
    }
}

void CMyClass::start() {
    std::barrier<??> barrier(threads_count, &func()); // ??
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The completion function of a `barrier` has to be invocable with zero arguments, which means you can't just pass a pointer to non-static member function (such a function still needs an argument: the class instance). Instead, you have to provide a lambda:

```cpp
std::barrier barrier(threads_count, [this]{ func(); });
```

Class template argument deduction (CTAD) will deduce the class template parameter from the type of the lambda, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you, tell me, how do I declare the `std::barrier` as a member of a class? (how use pointer to `std::barrier`)?

Comment: `Error C2338 N4861 [thread.barrier.class]/5: is_nothrow_invocable_v<CompletionFunction&> shall be true` :(